# Is Lionfish a kosher fish?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, fish

Lionfish has fins and scales so is Lionfish considered a kosher species of fish.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pterois

[image]

Comment: Not all scales are regular see [here] (http://shaalvim.co.il/torah/maayan-article.asp?id=366) an article which described the problem of some scales

Comment: The scales need to be visible to the naked eye and not embedded. That means that if you can pull off a scale without damaging the skin, it's kosher. If it'll damage the skin, it's not kosher. Pull the scale from the side that's closer to the tail, as the front part is what's connected. Don't believe any blanket rules that certain types of scales are always kosher. It needs hashgacha temidi from the time it's skinned, as you probably wouldn't know how to do it yourself without stung from it's venom, and use a kosher knife and cutting board. There's several varieties, each one has to be checked.

Comment: Source: kashrut.com

Comment: @user613 You mentioned an interesting rule. I recommend that you make your comments an answer.

Comment: @DanF But he asked about a specific fish, whether it's kosher or not, and I don't know.

Comment: @user613 Perhaps you can combine the two. I.e., you have the rule that you mentioned. Does lionfish conform to or negate the rule? I also think CRC has an article listing all kosher and non-kosher fish.

Comment: @DanF There are about 30000 (known) kinds of fish. I doubt they have such a list.

Comment: The New York Times says it's kosher http://www.nytimes.com/2014/12/14/opinion/sunday/can-seafood-be-kosher-and-sustainable.html third to last paragraph. Of course this isn't a reliable answer

Answer (score 2):

I happen to stumble on lionfish at Wholefoods. They cleaned and scaled the fish, but you can see that the skin is somewhat torn up. [image: lionfish]

I think it would be prudent to avoid until someone can show that the scales can be removed without damaging the skin.

Answer (score 1):

Lionfish have fins and cycloid scales which (I believe) makes them kosher. *Their scales are very easy to remove without damaging the skin* http://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/lionfish-facts.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LiF2lkc60k

Also, Lionfish are much easier to prepare than most people believe. Removing the venomous spines can be done with a simple pair of kitchen shears. They can be filleted without removing the spines, but if you would prefer to do so, you simply need to cut off the dorsal spines, anal spines and pelvic spines.

Lucky for us, because they are delicious and nutritious!

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya ReefGuard! Thanks for the answer. This answer could be improved with an explanation of the relevance of the ease of removal of lionfish scales, and especially with references to Jewish sources.

Comment: According to the CRC, the type of scales is not a reliable factor. "Q: What are some examples of fish with scales that are not kosher?  A: Sturgeon definitely has scales, but it is not kosher. Its scales are classified as “ganoid”, which means that they are covered with ganoin (similar in texture to fingernails) and cannot be removed without tearing the skin. Burbot has cycloid scales (one of the types often referred to as “always kosher”) yet because they are embedded, this fish is not kosher. Sand lances may have tiny scales, but since they are not visible, this fish is not kosher."

Comment: Here's the link to article [CRC kosher fish](http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/kosher_fish.php)

Comment: @menachem not all authorities agree with that definition of kosher scales